# Admob view not being loaded on QVGA device

Tags: android, admob, ads

My application has some ads that are being shown as expected on HGVA (320x480) and WVGA (480x800) devices. On the other hand, they're not being shown on QVGA (240x320) devices. Logcat prints the following:

**I/Ads     ( 1521): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)**

I know this is not the problem, because I'm having a satisfaction rate over 85%, and it's very uncommon not having an ad loaded on the other devices with a larger screen.

In fact, I've NEVER had an ad returned for QVGA devices.
I'm using Admob 4.1.1 and testing is set to false.

What's going wrong?

Comment: do you get ads served on QVGA in landscape mode? I was wondering if 240 isn't too small for ads to fit...

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might want to check this page about screen/banner sizes [Banner Sizes](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html)

> If there isn't enough space on the device's screen to display the ad, nothing will be shown.